# Why does my Pygame label not show up even though I copied from my other one that worked?

Tags: python, pygame

I am making a Pygame game and I have a label that every time you lose it should make the screen black and say GAME OVER. This is my code and the Label won't show up even though I copied it from my other label code and just changed it to label2. What is wrong?

```
if self.rect.colliderect(obstacle2.rect) or self.rect.colliderect(obstacle1.rect):
            obstacle2.kill()
            obstacle1.kill()
            player.kill()
            screenColor = BLACK
            default_font2 = pygame.font.get_default_font()
            font_renderer2 = pygame.font.Font(default_font2, 100)
            label2 = font_renderer2.render('GAME OVER', True, WHITE)
            label2_rect = label2.get_rect()
            label2_rect.center = screen_rect.center
            screen.blit(label2, label2_rect)
```

Comment: What is the shape of WHITE ? And is this all inside a class ?

Comment: Wdym shape of WHITE? and yes

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this code. Nobody can say why it doesn't work. Please stop asking questions with tiny snippets of code out of context. We need to know the control flow of the program. When is this code executed? All of your questions cannot be answered. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Ok sorry @Rabbid76 I changed it

Comment: Should I put in my entire code or this good enough?

Comment: You need to draw the label in the application loop. The condition `self.rect.colliderect(obstacle2.rect) or self.rect.colliderect(obstacle1.rect)` is just fulfilled in a single frame. Hence the label is just visible for a single frame and not noticeable.

Comment: So I would move this code into the main loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to draw the label in the application loop. The condition `self.rect.colliderect(obstacle2.rect) or self.rect.colliderect(obstacle1.rect)` is just fulfilled in a single frame. Hence the label is just visible for a single frame and not noticeable.

---

Before the application loop, add a `game_over` variable:

```py
game_over = False
```

Set the variable when the collision is detected:

```py
if self.rect.colliderect(obstacle2.rect) or self.rect.colliderect(obstacle1.rect):
    obstacle2.kill()
    obstacle1.kill()
    player.kill()
    screenColor = BLACK

    # [...]

    game_over = True
```

Draw the text in the application loop depending on `game_over`:

```py
# application loop
while True:

    # [...]

    if game_over
        # [...]

        screen.blit(label2, label2_rect)

    pygame.display.update()
```